# IONIC Google cordovaOauth not working

Tags: ionic-framework, google-signin

```
$cordovaOauth.google("client_id", ["email"]).then(function(result) {
        alert("Auth Success..!!");
        alert(result);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Auth Failed..!!" + error);
    });
```

Above code is used to sign in for google login from an ionic application on a ios device. I get below error

Please help me where am I going wrong with the code

[image]